# Workaround for ncurses multi-thread read and write

Tags: multithreading, ncurses, curses

This is what says on http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#multithread

> If you have a program which uses curses in more than one thread, you will almost certainly see odd behavior. That is because curses relies upon static variables for both input and output. Using one thread for input and other(s) for output cannot solve the problem, nor can extra screen updates help. This FAQ is not a tutorial on threaded programming.

Specifically, it mentions it is not safe even if input and output are done on separate threads. Would it be safe if we further use a mutex for the whole ncurses library so that at most one thread can be calling any ncurses function at a time? If not, what would be other cheap workarounds to use ncurses safely in multi-thread application?

I'm asking this question because I notice a real application often has its own event loop but relies on ncurses `getch` function to get keyboard input. But if the main thread is block waiting in its own event loop, then it has no chance to call `getch`. A seemingly applicable solution is to call `getch` in a different thread, which hasn't caused me a problem yet, but as what says above is actually not safe, and was verified by another user [here](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/529037). So I'm wondering what is the best way to merge `getch` into an application's own event loop.

I'm considering making `getch` non-blocking and waking up the main thread regularly (every 10-100 ms) to check if there is something to read. But this adds an additional delay between key events and makes the application less responsive. Also, I'm not sure if that would cause any problems with some ncurses internal delay such as `ESCDELAY`.

Another solution I'm considering is to poll stdin directly. But I guess ncurses should also be doing something like that and reading the same stream from two different places looks bad.

The text also mentions the "ncursest" or "ncursestw" libraries, but they seem to be less available, for example, if you are using a different language binding of curses. It would be great if there is a viable solution with the standard ncurses library.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910562/why-has-no-one-written-a-threadsafe-branch-of-the-ncurses-library) answer has some useful information for you.

Comment: @fredrik Thank you, I read that question actually. But as Thomas said that wasn't widely used by users. That's why I'm asking a solution with the standard library. Plus, I'm having a (probably) easier requirement here: I'm not asking for full multi-threading support, but being able to read stdin from a different thread is good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the thread-support, you're out of luck for using curses functions in more than one thread.  That's because most of the curses calls use static or global data.  The `getch` function for instance calls `refresh` which can update the whole screen—using the global pointers **`curscr`** and **`stdscr`**.  The difference in the thread-support configuration is that global values are converted to functions and mutex's added.

If you want to read *stdin* from a different thread and run *curses* in one thread, you probably can make that work by checking the ***file descriptor*** (i.e., **`0`**) for pending activity and alerting the thread which runs curses to tell it to read data.