# Schedule an asynchronous event that will complete when stdin has waiting data in boost::asio?

Tags: select, boost, boost-asio, stdin, ncurses

I'm using boost::asio with ncurses for a command-line game.  The game needs to draw on the screen at a fixed time interval, and other operations (e.g. networking or file operations) are also executed whenever necessary.  All these things can be done with `async_read()`/`async_write()` or equivalent on boost::asio.

However, I also need to read keyboard input, which (I think) comes from stdin.  The usual way to read input in ncurses is to call `getch()`, which can be configured to either blocking (wait until there is a character available for consumption) or non-blocking (return a sentinel value of there no characters available) mode.

Using blocking mode would necessitate running `getch()` on a separate thread, which doesn't play well with ncurses.  Using non-blocking mode, however, would cause my application to consume CPU time spinning in a loop until the user presses their keyboard.  I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809310/workaround-for-ncurses-multi-thread-read-and-write) answer, which suggests that we can add `stdin` to the list of file descriptors in a `select()` call, which would block until one of the file descriptors has new data.

Since I'm using boost::asio, I can't directly use `select()`.  I can't call `async_read`, because that would consume the character, leaving `getch()` with nothing to read.  Is there something in boost::asio like `async_read`, but merely checks the existence of input without consuming it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to use the posix stream descriptor to watch for input on file descriptor `0`:

```
ba::posix::stream_descriptor d(io, 0);
input_loop = [&](error_code ec) {
    if (!ec) {
        program.on_input();
        d.async_wait(ba::posix::descriptor::wait_type::wait_read, input_loop);
    }
};
```

There, `program::on_input()` would call `getch()` with no `timeout()` until it returns `ERR`:

```
struct Program {
    Program() {
        initscr();
        ESCDELAY = 0;
        timeout(0);
        cbreak(); 

        noecho();
        keypad(stdscr, TRUE); // receive special keys

        clock   = newwin(2, 40, 0, 0);
        monitor = newwin(10, 40, 2, 0);

        syncok(clock, true);    // automatic updating
        syncok(monitor, true);

        scrollok(monitor, true); // scroll the input monitor window
    }
    ~Program() {
        delwin(monitor);
        delwin(clock);
        endwin();
    }

    void on_clock() {
        wclear(clock);

        char buf[32];
        time_t t = time(NULL);
        if (auto tmp = localtime(&t)) {
            if (strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%T", tmp) == 0) {
                strncpy(buf, "[error formatting time]", sizeof(buf));
            }
        } else {
            strncpy(buf, "[error getting time]", sizeof(buf));
        }

        wprintw(clock, "Async: %s", buf);
        wrefresh(clock);
    }

    void on_input() {
        for (auto ch = getch(); ch != ERR; ch = getch()) {
            wprintw(monitor, "received key %d ('%c')\n", ch, ch);
        }
        wrefresh(monitor);
    }

    WINDOW *monitor = nullptr;
    WINDOW *clock = nullptr;
};
```

With the following `main` program you'd run it for 10 seconds (because `Program` doesn't yet know how to exit):

```
int main() {
    Program program;

    namespace ba = boost::asio;
    using boost::system::error_code;
    using namespace std::literals;

    ba::io_service io;
    std::function<void(error_code)> input_loop, clock_loop;

    // Reading input when ready on stdin
    ba::posix::stream_descriptor d(io, 0);
    input_loop = [&](error_code ec) {
        if (!ec) {
            program.on_input();
            d.async_wait(ba::posix::descriptor::wait_type::wait_read, input_loop);
        }
    };

    // For fun, let's also update the time
    ba::high_resolution_timer tim(io);
    clock_loop = [&](error_code ec) {
        if (!ec) {
            program.on_clock();
            tim.expires_from_now(100ms);
            tim.async_wait(clock_loop);
        }
    };

    input_loop(error_code{});
    clock_loop(error_code{});
    io.run_for(10s);
}
```

This works:

[image]

### Full Listing

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/posix/descriptor.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "ncurses.h"

#define CTRL_R    18
#define CTRL_C    3
#define TAB       9
#define NEWLINE   10
#define RETURN    13
#define ESCAPE    27
#define BACKSPACE 127
#define UP        72
#define LEFT      75
#define RIGHT     77
#define DOWN      80

struct Program {
    Program() {
        initscr();
        ESCDELAY = 0;
        timeout(0);
        cbreak(); 

        noecho();
        keypad(stdscr, TRUE); // receive special keys

        clock   = newwin(2, 40, 0, 0);
        monitor = newwin(10, 40, 2, 0);

        syncok(clock, true);    // automatic updating
        syncok(monitor, true);

        scrollok(monitor, true); // scroll the input monitor window
    }
    ~Program() {
        delwin(monitor);
        delwin(clock);
        endwin();
    }

    void on_clock() {
        wclear(clock);

        char buf[32];
        time_t t = time(NULL);
        if (auto tmp = localtime(&t)) {
            if (strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%T", tmp) == 0) {
                strncpy(buf, "[error formatting time]", sizeof(buf));
            }
        } else {
            strncpy(buf, "[error getting time]", sizeof(buf));
        }

        wprintw(clock, "Async: %s", buf);
        wrefresh(clock);
    }

    void on_input() {
        for (auto ch = getch(); ch != ERR; ch = getch()) {
            wprintw(monitor, "received key %d ('%c')\n", ch, ch);
        }
        wrefresh(monitor);
    }

    WINDOW *monitor = nullptr;
    WINDOW *clock = nullptr;
};

int main() {
    Program program;

    namespace ba = boost::asio;
    using boost::system::error_code;
    using namespace std::literals;

    ba::io_service io;
    std::function<void(error_code)> input_loop, clock_loop;

    // Reading input when ready on stdin
    ba::posix::stream_descriptor d(io, 0);
    input_loop = [&](error_code ec) {
        if (!ec) {
            program.on_input();
            d.async_wait(ba::posix::descriptor::wait_type::wait_read, input_loop);
        }
    };

    // For fun, let's also update the time
    ba::high_resolution_timer tim(io);
    clock_loop = [&](error_code ec) {
        if (!ec) {
            program.on_clock();
            tim.expires_from_now(100ms);
            tim.async_wait(clock_loop);
        }
    };

    input_loop(error_code{});
    clock_loop(error_code{});
    io.run_for(10s);
}
```

Comment: This seems to work here, I didn't realise `boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor` had `async_wait()`.  For Windows, I used `boost::asio::windows::object_handle waiter(ctx, GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE))`, which has a similar `async_wait()` function.

Comment: Indeed. In older Boost Versions there was the [`null_buffers` technique](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html) which would still require `async_read` or `async_write`. So the new interface is clearly nicer (part of the Networking TS as far as I know)