# Graphic problems with the ncurses library in C

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

***Premise:*** I'm programming a client-server game in C. The game graphics are built entirely with the support of the ncurses.h library (to be specific **ncursesw**).

***Problem:*** The game is programmed in a Linux environment (Ubuntu - 19.04) on a virtual machine on Windows 10. When I start the game in the same programming environment (Linux -> Ubuntu - 19.04), the game graphics works perfectly:

Screenshot: Working graphics Linux (Ubuntu - 19.04) on a virtual machine Win10

[image: Screenshot: Working graphics Linux (Ubuntu - 19.04) on a virtual machine Win10]

However, in any other environment like WLS (Windows Subsystem for Linux), Linux (Ubuntu 19.04/19.10 **not on virtual machine**) etc.. Graphics are not working properly *(One of the stranger things is that sometimes the graphics are initialized correctly)*:

Screenshot: Graphics not working properly Linux (Ubuntu - 19.04)

[image: Screenshot: Graphics not working properly Linux (Ubuntu - 19.04)]

***Code:*** [full server code here](https://pastebin.com/bcE4vAF1) Below the main graphic function:

```
int initInterface(char* blueprint){

    char basicComponent[1];
    int bytesReaded;
    int hudFile;
    pthread_t tidUpdateChat;
    LpMsg msgChat;
    char msg[CHAT_WIDTH];

    sleep(1);

    /* Verifica la compatibilitÃ  dei colori con il terminale */
    if(!has_colors()){
      endwin();
      printf("\a\n\x1b[31m <!> Il tuo terminale non supporta i colori.\n\n\x1b[0m");
      return 1;
    }
    start_color();

    /* Inizializzazione della grafica */
    if((hudFile = open(blueprint, O_RDONLY)) == -1){
      endwin();
      printf("\a\n\x1b[31m <!> Errore durante l'inizializzazione dell'interfaccia grafica.\n\n\x1b[0m");
      return 1;
    }
    while((bytesReaded = read(hudFile, basicComponent, 1)) > 0){
      if(bytesReaded == -1){
        endwin();
        printf("\a\n\x1b[31m <!> Errore durante l'inizializzazione dell'interfaccia grafica.\n\n\x1b[0m");
        return 1;
      }
      basicComponent[bytesReaded] = '\0';
      basicComponent[0] = initStructures(basicComponent[0]);
      if(basicComponent[0] == FIELD_BLUEPRINT){
        printw(" ");
      } else{
        printw("%s", basicComponent);
      }
    }
    close(hudFile);

    /* Disabilito la ristampa dei caratteri catturati da getch */
    noecho();

    /* Rendo il cursore invisibile */
    curs_set(0);

    /* Definizione dei vari design */
    init_color(COLOR_BLACK, 784, 803, 694);
    init_color(COLOR_WHITE, 8, 0, 60);

    init_pair(DESIGN_THEME, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_WHITE);
    init_pair(DESIGN_RED, COLOR_RED, COLOR_WHITE);
    init_pair(DESIGN_CYAN, COLOR_CYAN, COLOR_WHITE);
    init_pair(DESIGN_YELLOW, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_WHITE);
    init_pair(DESIGN_GREEN, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_WHITE);
    init_pair(DESIGN_BLUE, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_WHITE);

    init_pair(DESIGN_GRASS, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_GREEN);
    init_pair(DESIGN_BRICK, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_WHITE);
    init_pair(DESIGN_PACKET, COLOR_RED, COLOR_GREEN);
    init_pair(DESIGN_LOCATION, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_MAGENTA);
    init_pair(DESIGN_PLAYER, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_GREEN);

    /* Cambio il colore dello sfondo e del testo */
    bkgd(COLOR_PAIR(DESIGN_THEME));

    sprintf(msg, "Sono in ascolto sulla porta %d!", listenerPort);
    if((msgChat = allocMsg(msg, DESIGN_BLUE, false)) != NULL){
      pthread_create(&tidUpdateChat, NULL, updateChat, msgChat);
    }

    /* Commit della grafica */
    refresh();

    return 0;
}
```

***Some information:***

- In main i initialize the locale and the ncurses window.
- The graphics are initialized from of a file, in practice I am going to read character by character from the file. Here the file: [graphics.txt](https://pastebin.com/uca9UGda)

What could be the problem? Could it be a character encoding error? If more information is needed, please ask. Thank to all.

Comment: See here ... https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#compatible_tic ... scroll up and down. Wish you luck and patience :)

Comment: Actually the `pthread_create` hints at a problem which would make this a duplicate.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: If you're using ncurses in multi-threads, it won't work reliably [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809310/workaround-for-ncurses-multi-thread-read-and-write)

Comment: Strange, I'm sure I've protected every variable (such as the cursor) with mutex.