# python curses multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, curses

I have a problem with curses. When I try to display text in several windows, something strange happens to the program. Strange characters appear throughout the window.

I know that this seems to be fixed in ncurses, but python does not have this library. I ask for help!

```
from signal import signal, SIGINT
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import curses


def main(scr):
    firstT = Thread(target=thr1)
    firstT.setDaemon(True)
    secondT = Thread(target=thr2)
    secondT.setDaemon(True)
    secondT.start()
    firstT.start()
    scr.getch()


def thr1():
    counter = 0
    win = curses.newwin(1, 5, 1, 1)
    while True:
        win.addstr(0, 0, str(counter))
        win.refresh()
        counter += 1
        sleep(0.5)


def thr2():
    counter = 0
    win1 = curses.newwin(1, 5, 2, 1)

    while True:
        win1.addstr(0, 0, str(counter))
        win1.refresh()
        counter += 1
        sleep(0.1)


def handler(signal_received, frame):
    curses.endwin()
    curses.curs_set(1)
    exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal(SIGINT, handler)
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

[image: output]

Comment: It's a configurable (build-time) option in ncurses which you probably don't have, and which python doesn't use anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Workaround for ncurses multi-thread read and write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809310/workaround-for-ncurses-multi-thread-read-and-write)

Comment: @ThomasDickey not fully. I know about this, but i don't know how to fix this.