# When I print from a thread, it gives me weird output in C using ncurses

Tags: c, multithreading, time, pthreads, ncurses

this is my thread for the timer which i use:

```
void *timer(void *arg){
    
    current = time(0);
    stop = current + 30;
    while (1){
        current = time (0);
        if (current <= stop){
            now=stop-current;
            mvprintw(0,0,"%d",now);
            refresh();
        }
    }
    
    return NULL;
}
```

Edit (from comments)...

i forgot to mention that im using :

```
pthread_t timerth; pthread_create(&timerth, NULL, timer, NULL);
```

i need to print the "timerleft" value but the output looks like this :

[image]

Is there any way to print it normally? Am I missing something?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Workaround for ncurses multi-thread read and write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809310/workaround-for-ncurses-multi-thread-read-and-write).  There's more than one possibility, but in the end this is a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to save and restore the current cursor position??

```
void *timer(void *arg) {
    int x, y;
    getyx(stdscr, y, x);

    /* ... */

    move(y, x);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: same result. i forgot to mention that im using :
pthread_t timerth;
pthread_create(&timerth, NULL, timer, NULL);

Comment: Oh, well! Worth a shot though, I think.

Comment: Well, you'd need to use locking if anything else uses the screen at the same time. Cause another thread could do something in between

Comment: sounds good but. what exactly do you think? im relatively new to programming so i don't really know what to do

Comment: @JakubKolesár What I think ikegami suggests is that you synchronize all operations that writes to the ncurses screen. You could use a common mutex for all those operations: Lock the mutex, write to screen, unlock the mutex.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add \r at the end of print string like so

```
mvprintw(0,0,"%d \r",now);
```

Comment: still the same result ;/

Comment: have you tried it without the coordinates?
`mvprintw("%d \r",now);`
or `mvprintw("%d \r\n",now);`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).