# Ncurses - Printw is not printing instantly in multithreaded async environment

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, ncurses

I am developing CLI application In `Ncurses` but got stuck with this problem with `printw` unpredictable behavior with threads communicating in async manner .

My CLI is one thread, say, T1. The application is integrated with CLI. Application is separate thread thread, say T2.

**Now I explain two scenarios :**

**To begin with T1 is listening to user input, and T2 is blocked on the condition variable. Applicable for both scenarios.**

**Scenario 1 (`printw` works fine)**

1. User type out CLI command and hit enter
2. T1 executes and fill T2 internal buffers with User Input Data
3. T1 signals T2
4. T1 block itself on its own CV ( waiting for T2 to finish work )
5. T2 executes and process user Data ( here T2 if invokes `printw` then o/p is instantly visible on screen, no problem at all )
6. T2 signals T1
7. T2 blocks on its CV again.
8. T1 resumed and awaits for user input again.

All steps works like charm.

Now coming to async scenario.

**Scenario 2 (`printw` dont seems to be working)**

1. User type out CLI command and hit enter
2. T1 executes and fill T2 internal buffers with User Input Data
3. T1 signals T2
4. T1 comes back and wait for next user data ( no blocking on CV here )
5. T2 executes and process user Data ( here T2 if invokes `printw` then o/p is not visible )
6. T2 blocks on its CV again after finishing the work.

You can see, in scenario2, threads are not tighly synchronized ( intended behavior ). T1 do not waits for T2 to finish. Internal buffers are mutex protected ofcourse ( as it is typical reader-writer problem ).

My question is  - In scenario 1 , `printw` works good, but in scenario 2, 'printw' from previous CLI command output only when user type out next CLI command. I suspect some `printw` buffering problem and tried several solutions but no success.

**Solutions I tried :**

1. T1 and T2 both call to `initscr()` --  did not work. Only T1 calls initscr( ) during init now.
2. insert `refresh()` after `printw` in T2 - no success.
3. inserted another `printw("\n")` immediately after `printw` in T2, thinking if `printw` is line buffered. Still, it did not work.

**Here is the sample output :**

`Soft-Firewall>$ config node H1 protocol isis interface eth1` *<< CLI triggered*

`Parse Success` *<< CLI execution is successful ( All steps of scenario 2 are executed. This is printed by T1 in step4 scneario 2 )*

`Soft-Firewall>$`        *<<<< CLI offers new prompt to user for next cmd. Now I hit enter ( this `enter press` simply move cursor to next line using ncurses `move` API )*

`Error : Protocol not enabled on Device`  *<<< output of prev cmd now appear from `printw`*

`Soft-Firewall>$`   *<<< new promt for the user to type new cmd*

You can see that following error msg is not printed until i press entery key. This error msg was printed by T2.

**Err msg :** `Error : Protocol not enabled on Device`

Pls help. My whole project is on toll because of this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Workaround for ncurses multi-thread read and write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809310/workaround-for-ncurses-multi-thread-read-and-write)