# Thread not printing to curses screen correctly

Tags: c, pthreads, curses

I have an assignment where I need to make a game using threads and the curses library. I have mostly finished the program, but the player icon is not getting printed to the curses screen even though the function should be doing that. The other functionality of the function is working, it's just that nothing is being printed. For example, when I press `q` the program will terminate like it is supposed to.

Here is the function itself:

```
void *run_rocket( void *rocket ) {
  object_t * rocket1 = (object_t *) rocket;
  int c;
  int row = rocket1->row;
  mvaddch( rocket1->row, rocket1->col, rock );
  curse_refresh();
  while( running ){
    c = getchar();
    if( c == KEY_UP ){
      row = row - 1;
      rocket1->row = row;
      mvaddch( row+1, rocket1->col, ' ' );
      mvaddch( row, rocket1->col, rock );
    } else if( c == KEY_DOWN ){
        if( row!=bheight ){
          row = row + 1;
          rocket1->row = row;
          mvaddch( row-1, rocket1->col, ' ' );
          mvaddch( row, rocket1->col, rock );
        }
    } else if( c == 'q' ){
        running = false;
    }
    if( row == 0 ){
      running = false;
      int hgt = bheight/2;
      mvprintw( hgt, 0, "Congratulations!  You won!");
      mvprintw( (hgt - 1), 0, "Press 'q' to exit.");
    }
    curse_refresh();
  }
  destroy_rocket(rocket);
  return NULL;
}
```

and this is how I start the thread

```
pthread_t rocket;
check = pthread_create( &rocket, NULL, run_rocket, obj_rock );
if( check != 0 ){
  return 1;
}
```

I have only tried small changes because I have no idea what the problem, since I have another function that calls `mvaddch` the same way and that one works.

Comment: [Curses doesn't seem to be thread-safe by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910562/why-has-no-one-written-a-threadsafe-branch-of-the-ncurses-library).

Comment: This answers your question: [Workaround for ncurses multi-thread read and write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809310/workaround-for-ncurses-multi-thread-read-and-write)